# Move data from one drive to another drive

Tags: command-line

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 as a LiveCD in-order to move data from one drive to another drive because my previous OS crashed and I don't have my files backed up. Unfortunately, it is in C: drive. So I request you all help me to move my files as I don't have any info about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in the Ubuntu desktop, when pressing the "Windows" key (the one between Ctrl and Alt), you open the dash. There, you can type to search. Type "disk utility" and hit return. You should open a program like the one from this screen-shot:

[image: this screenshot].

There, in the left column you can see a list of your local drives. Find the one you are looking for, click on it, and you'll see in the main panel a description of the internal partitions of that drive. Click on the one you want and click the button that [**mounts**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29) that partition. That way, you'll be able to access your files through the file manager.

You can then plug a USB flashdrive to save your files, or upload them to the internet.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo blkid
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Ubuntu 12.10 i386" TYPE="iso9660" this is the output for above commamd. in Disks i can only see my dvd and other memory

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple :)

Basically what you've to do is to open a file manager. When you'll open on the left-side panel your drives will be listed. Your `C:` drive which is for Windows will also be listed. It would not be the same name if no Label was given to the drive `C:`.

Just click it to open (or right click and `mount`) the drive , from there you can copy your files very easily.

Ubuntu is often used as a rescue disk.

Reply if you get any type of error or message. Or you need any assistance.

Comment: @hasmukh: In Ubuntu 12.10 it would be of different name like **Disks**(search in dash). If you're still not able to find it then the last option is to mount the partitions manually. And this would be a little long process. So for this you've to provide the output of this command: `sudo blkid`. Edit your question and post the output of this command.